# MySQL GROUP BY and limiting joins

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following three tables which I am trying to perform a query on:

**orders**

```
id

created_at
```

**vouchers**

```
id

order_id

initial_value

current_value
```

**vouchers_used_in_orders**

```
voucher_id

order_id

amount_used

value_before

value_after
```

A voucher is purchased in an order, the id of this order is then saved to the voucher to keep a record of when it was purchased.

At a later date, the voucher can then be used to purchase goods in another order.  Each voucher has a cash value, so can be used in multiple orders until their value is fully used up.

I am trying to come up with a query which will group voucher purchases by the year and month they were purchased and show how many were purhcased and how much time passed before they were first used up to a maximum of twelve months.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
YEAR(o.created_at) AS year_purchased,
MONTH(o.created_at) AS month_purchased,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 1, 1)) AS number_sold,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 0, 1)) AS number_used,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 1, 0)) AS number_not_used,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_0,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_1,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_2,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_3,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 4 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_4,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_5,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 6 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_6,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 7 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 7 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_7,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 8 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 8 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_8,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 9 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_9,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 10 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 10 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_10,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 11 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_11,
SUM(IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 12 MONTH)), 1, 0)) AS number_used_month_12
FROM vouchers v
INNER JOIN orders o
ON o.id = v.order_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vouchers_used_in_orders vu
ON vu.voucher_id = v.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders vuo
ON vuo.id = vu.id
GROUP BY
YEAR(o.created_at), MONTH(o.created_at)
ORDER BY
YEAR(o.created_at), MONTH(o.created_at)
```

This counts the purchased vouchers correctly if they have not been used however once they start to get used, the outer joins cause the vouchers to be counted multiple times.  Also, it counts each use of a voucher, when I only want the first use.

Can anyone help?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use a COUNT DISTINCT on the voucher id? (You will need to set the false condition in the if statement to be null so they are not counter)

```
SELECT
YEAR(o.created_at) AS year_purchased,
MONTH(o.created_at) AS month_purchased,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 1, 1)) AS number_sold,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 0, 1)) AS number_used,
SUM(IF(v.current_value = v.initial_value, 1, 0)) AS number_not_used,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) AS number_used_month_0,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_1,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 2 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_2,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 3 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_3,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 4 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_4,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 5 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_5,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 6 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_6,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 7 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 7 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_7,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 8 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 8 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_8,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 9 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 9 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_9,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 10 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 10 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_10,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 11 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 11 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_11,
COUNT(DISTINCT IF(YEAR(vuo.created_at) = YEAR(o.created_at + INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND MONTH(vuo.created_at) = (MONTH(o.created_at + INTERVAL 12 MONTH)), vuo.voucher_id, null)) )) AS number_used_month_12
FROM vouchers v
INNER JOIN orders o
ON o.id = v.order_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN vouchers_used_in_orders vu
ON vu.voucher_id = v.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders vuo
ON vuo.id = vu.id
GROUP BY
YEAR(o.created_at), MONTH(o.created_at)
ORDER BY
YEAR(o.created_at), MONTH(o.created_at)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should give you almost all you are looking for.  In addition to the counts per month, I also added the total amount used per those months.  I first started a query to get the voucher, its initial date and that plus 12 months per your concern.  I am pre-computing the months once at each respective "per Voucher" basis so it can help simplify your SUM( IF() ) constructs for aggregations.  For detecting single count of vouchers, in my prequery (V1),
I retained the original order associated with the purchase of the voucher.  So by using that, I can do a SUM( IF() ) of that same order ID.  If its the one, it gets counted in the VouchersUsed.  With a left join to the voucher used table, if that comes back as null, then there are no instances of it being used and would be a NULL value.

You'll notice, I also took a precaution to prevent including the original order via the LEFT JOIN by explicitly preventing the order ID used to PURCHASE the voucher from getting counted and falsely throwing off a count.

```
  LEFT JOIN Vouchers_Used_In_Orders VUIO
     ON V1.ID = VUIO.Voucher_ID
     AND NOT V1.OriginalOrderID = VUIO.Order_ID
```

The only element I can't really test, and not having MySQL now is the

SUM( IF( VUIO.Voucher_ID = null, 1, 0 )) as VouchersNotUsed,

I think it will go, but may need to change it to SUM( IF( VUIO.Voucher_ID is null, 1, 0)).  Hope this helps you out.

```
SELECT 
      YEAR( v1.VoucherStarted ) as VoucherYear,
      MONTH( v1.VoucherStarted ) as VoucherMonth,
      COUNT( distinct( v1.ID )) as UniqueVouchers,
      SUM( IF( v1.OriginalOrderID = O.ID, 1, 0 )) as VouchersUsed,
      SUM( IF( VUIO.Voucher_ID = null, 1, 0 )) as VouchersNotUsed,
      SUM( IF( v1.OriginalOrderID = O.ID, 0, 1 )) as TimesVouchersUsed,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.VoucherStarted AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus1Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month1Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.VoucherStarted AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus1Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month1Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus1Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus2Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month2Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus1Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus2Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month2Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus2Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus3Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month3Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus2Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus3Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month3Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus3Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus4Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month3Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus3Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus4Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month3Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus4Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus5Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month4Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus4Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus5Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month4Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus5Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus6Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month5Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus5Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus6Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month5Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus6Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus7Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month6Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus6Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus7Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month6Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus7Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus8Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month7Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus7Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus8Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month7Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus8Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus9Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month8Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus8Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus9Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month8Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus9Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus10Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month9Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus9Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus10Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month9Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus10Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus11Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month10Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus10Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus11Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month10Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus11Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus12Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month11Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus11Month AND O.Created_At < v1.Plus12Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month11Amt,

      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus12Month ), 1, 0 ) as Month12Cnt,
      SUM( IF( O.Created_At >= v1.Plus12Month ), VUIO.Amount_Used , 0 ) as Month12Amt

   from 
      ( SELECT
              v.id,
              v.initial_value,
              v.order_id as OriginalOrderID
              vo.created_at as VoucherStarted,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 1 MONTH ) as Plus1Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 2 MONTH ) as Plus2Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 3 MONTH ) as Plus3Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 4 MONTH ) as Plus4Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 5 MONTH ) as Plus5Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 6 MONTH ) as Plus6Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 7 MONTH ) as Plus7Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 8 MONTH ) as Plus8Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 9 MONTH ) as Plus9Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 10 MONTH ) as Plus10Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 12 MONTH ) as Plus11Month,
              date_add( vo.created_at, INTERVAL 12 MONTH ) as Plus12Month
           from
              vouchers v
                 join orders vo
                    ON v.order_id = vo.order_id ) V1

      LEFT JOIN Vouchers_Used_In_Orders VUIO
         ON V1.ID = VUIO.Voucher_ID
         AND NOT V1.OriginalOrderID = VUIO.Order_ID

         LEFT JOIN Orders O
            ON VUIO.Order_ID = O.ID
            AND O.Created_At between V1.VoucherStarted and V1.Plus12Month

   GROUP BY
      YEAR( v1.VoucherStarted ),
      MONTH( v1.VoucherStarted )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd combine 'vouchers' and 'orders' into:

```
 voucher_orders:
     ID
     purchase_date
     value
```

Then have 'voucher_use':

```
     VoucherID
     Amount
     use_date
```

To get stats:

```
 select voucher_order.ID as v0, voucher_order.purchase_date, v2.ud left join
 (  select min( use_date ) ud from voucher_use as v1 where v1.VoucherID = v0.VoucherID limit 1 ) as v2 on v0.VoucherID = v2.VoucherID group by v0.purchase_date order by v0.purchase_date;
```

Do all your 'value remaining' stuff in code. This info doesn't need to be stored.